# Why will Xcode 9.4.1 not allow me to use the UIImage pngData() instance method?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am trying to use the pngData() instance method of the UIImage class of Apple's UIKit Framework according to this documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624096-pngdata

When I type the method in Xcode, I get an error saying:

Value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'pngData'

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let image = UIImage(named: "moroni.png")

    let dataImage = image.pngData() // Value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'pngData'

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know why the Document's page display wrong, but your function

```
image.pngData()
```

can only use from Swift 4.2 (and later, maybe), but your Xcode 9.4.1 only supports to Swift 4.1.

From the older Swift version, you can (only) using

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(_ image: UIImage) -> Data?
```